# .net set landing pages from start

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have page, which content and URL changes from database. However, I want to set URL like

> localhost:xxxx/MyPage

Now I got

> localhost:xxxx/Pages/MyPage

which I don't need. What can I do for change it?
My route

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "LandingPage", 
    url: "Pages/{*urltitle}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "LandPage", urltitle = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

My code for change content and URL

```
public ActionResult LandPage()
    {
      string temp = RouteData.Values["urltitle"].ToString();
            var item = RepositoryManager.Instanse.LandingContentRepository.GetItemByURL(temp);
            IEnumerable<LandingContent> list = new List<LandingContent>() { item };
            ViewBag.HtmlStr = item.HTMLText;
            return View(ViewBag);
    }
```

Comment: switch mappings and update url by removing Pages from template

Comment: @Nkosi I did that, and I got this **http://localhost:xxxxx/Admin/LandPage?urltitle=mypage**

Comment: Show how you updated routes

Comment: @Nkosi `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
            routes.MapRoute(
        "LandingPage", 
        "{*urltitle}",
        new { controller = "Admin", action = "LandPage", urltitle = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );`

Comment: which is what i did suggest. what is generating the link you got?

Comment: @Nkosi How can I look at it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127057/discussion-between-nkosi-and--).

Comment: @Nkosi are you here?

Comment: @Nkosi are you here?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I kinda solved it
my final route

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "LandPage",
        url: "{segment}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "LandingPage" }
```

And in HomeController you do this

```
  [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult LandingPage(string segment)
    {some logic}
```